# VBA Homogenize Conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-statements

I'm working with a file that has allot of Conditional formatting applied in some cases to bigger ranges. 
Whenever I add a row or a column, that conditional formatting breaks into 2, resulting in allot of split rules and an increase in file size. 
I could do a lookup by conditional formatting formula, but the formula shifts with every split, so searching for the same formula will not work:

```
=$E167<>$E166
=$E159<>$E158
```

Is there anything i can do to prevent this splitting and join current areas that have split? I'm interested in a way to find them.

Comment: I do feel your pain. The only way I can think of is through VBA :S. Maybe store your conditional formatting rules and re-apply them after you insert a row/column